# Xamarin.iOS UITest does not run with category

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

I have a lot of uitests for Xamarin.Forms app. These tests under categories. (For example LoginTest category has 10 tests, InboxTest category has 40 tests etc.) When I select 1 category (or when I select more than categories) and run it on iOS simulator, firstly tests of these categories runs, but after a while some tests don't run.

And I encounter this error:

```
Connection closed
Stack trace:
at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.RemoteProcessConnection.SendMessage[RT] (MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.BinaryMessage`1[RT] message) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.Execution/RemoteProcessConnection.cs:374
at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit.External.ExternalTestRunner.Run (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit.External.IRemoteEventListener listener, System.String[] nameFilter, System.String path, System.String suiteName, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] supportAssemblies, System.String testRunnerType, System.String testRunnerAssembly, System.String crashLogFile) [0x00099] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/ExternalTestRunner.cs:91
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread () [0x001b6] in C:\A_work\107\s\src\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading\JoinableTask.cs:916
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1[T].CompleteOnCurrentThread () [0x00000] in C:\A_work\107\s\src\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading\JoinableTask`1.cs:84
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] asyncMethod, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions) [0x0000e] in C:\A_work\107\s\src\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading\JoinableTaskFactory.cs:505
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] asyncMethod) [0x00000] in C:\A_work\107\s\src\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading\JoinableTaskFactory.cs:484
at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit.NUnitAssemblyTestSuite.RunUnitTest (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.UnitTest test, System.String suiteName, System.String pathName, System.String testName, MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.TestContext testContext) [0x00265] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnitAssemblyTestSuite.cs:535
at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit.NUnitTestSuite.OnRun (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.TestContext testContext) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit/NUnitTestSuite.cs:79
at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.UnitTest.Run (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.TestContext testContext) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/Services/UnitTest.cs:351
```

When I run it one by one, they run.
My Visual Studio mac version is 8.8.4 (up to date)
Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent version is 0.22.1
Xamarin.UITest version is 3.0.12

What must I do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi, if you're using Xamarin TestCloud, it's suggested to ask for App Center support in its portal as TestCloud is a part of App Center, and issues usually related with server side.

Comment: Thank you for reply @NicoleLu-MSFT, I run uitests on my local pc. (I open tests section on visual studio for mac, I right click category, I click run tests) Is it related to the server side?

Comment: there's a connection broken from the error message, so looks like something related with server side. We can't be sure of it since not much info provided. Could you please provide a minimal demo that can reproduce your issue?